# Spring intercept exceptions in one class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot for my REST service. Now I want to implement a general logging at a central place. Here is my structure:

REST

```
@GetMapping(value="/rest/test/{userId}")
public User getUserById(@PathVariable String userId) {
   return userService.findById(userId);
}
```

UserService

```
public User findById(@NotNull String userId) {
  if(noUserFound) {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException();
  }
}
```

My goal is to have a central class that intercepts all exceptions (also BeanValidation exceptions) and get the following information:

- The API endpoint that was called
- All parameters that were passed
- The exception and its message
- The username/id that sent the request (I am using Keycloak with OpenAuth)

Is there a possibility to do that, maybe without annotating every method with `@ExceptionHandler`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use @ControllerAdvice to achieve this goal.

Here is a sample code:

```java
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    // Build-in exceptions, this one is for Validation errors
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
            MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request
    ) {
        // info about endpoint
        var path = request.getDescription(false);
        // request params map
        var params = request.getParameterMap();
        // authenticated principal
        var user = request.getUserPrincipal();
        log.debug("path: {}, params: {}, user: {}", path, params.keySet(), user.getName());
        return super.handleMethodArgumentNotValid(ex, headers, status, request);
    }

    // Custom exception
    @ExceptionHandler(NoAccessException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Error> noAccessException(NoAccessException ex, WebRequest request) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
                .body(Error.builder().message(ex.getMessage()).build());
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks great, I will try this approach. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just one question: what if I just want to monitor all exceptions and do not want to set the status etc. myself like in your ExceptionHandler?

Comment: To do this, You need to override all methods of ResponseEntityExceptionHandler, do logging, and then call super method. Also, don't handle your custom exceptions if you want default behavior for them.

Comment: For custom exceptions - default behavior is IInternalError and they are handled in this method handleExceptionInternal

Comment: No the problem is that there are predefined responses with HTTP states for some exceptions and that is lost when I use the exception handler. So do I really need to override each exception? ...

Comment: Yep. I was a bit wrong, you don't need to override all methods. Just override handleExceptionInternal and add logging. All other methods use this one to make response.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just a little hint for a dirty workaround:re-trhrowing the exception with throw ex; will make spring return to the default handling with setting the HTTP status and the corresponding response body and headers ;) Using Exception.class you can monitor all exceptions and then return to the call flow of spring

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@ControllerAdvice`. Example code from https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-rest-error-handling-example/

```
@ControllerAdvice
 public class CustomGlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler 
 {

//...

// @Validate For Validating Path Variables and Request Parameters
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
public void constraintViolationException(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
}

// error handle for @Valid
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object>
handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
                             HttpHeaders headers,
                             HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

    Map<String, Object> body = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    body.put("timestamp", new Date());
    body.put("status", status.value());

    //Get all fields errors
    List<String> errors = ex.getBindingResult()
            .getFieldErrors()
            .stream()
            .map(x -> x.getDefaultMessage())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    body.put("errors", errors);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(body, headers, status);

}}
```